# What could be the problem if there is only one sealer in private network with PoA Consensus?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, security, poa

I have a private network created using geth and I want to use it as a decentralized database. Currently, I'm testing the network using 3 nodes which one of the nodes as a validator (hence only one sealer).

At first, I thought that having more sealers will make transactions faster to be mined but there could be problems with that like all the sealers stop mining because they wait for each other to sign the block and transactions are stuck in a pending state.

Using only one sealer is not posing any problem about stuck transactions. But, I'm worried this will be posing another problem I don't know. Is this kind of private network okay? I feel like security problems could rise from here.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit broad, so here are some leads. Also this is more of a comment, but it's a bit too big for that.

But first of all, do not use ethereum as a decentralized "database".

I do not know what you store, but storing large amount of data is not optimized and is not the purpose of ethereum.

Back to your question, here is something that may be problematic:

- What happens if your sealer is not connected to your other nodes anymore ? (network problems, etc.)
- Actually,I do not have any other thing in mind, but note that a decentralized network with one centralized block sealer is kind of counter productive...

> I thought that having more sealers will make transactions faster to be
> mined but there could be problems with that like all the sealers stop
> mining

It is a decentralized network, dedicated to decentralized mining, developped on purpose to handle multiple miners with dedicated concensus. What reason makes you think multiple sealers would be a problem ?

Comment: The data is not that big. I use it only to save the hash I'm getting from uploading data to IPFS and some small fields. I use ethereum to secure data from anonymous change because by using ethereum, anonymous change must change 50%+1 node's blockchain to finally change it. Network problem is not concerned currently and I found that by using more than one node as sealer (but the account is same) will prevent network problem.

Comment: I'm facing this issue when trying to use more than two sealer [this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/18402)